# How to build a simple layout to add a bottom menu in Android Layout

Tags: android-menu

I am a new Android Programmer. When building a Android App, I need to add a bottom menu in Android Layout. Any idea to guide me to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative layout for your root view. The menu will be a linear layout with horizontal orientation and you will place your styled buttons there.